# Recursion with Python's turtle module (pythonds book)

Tags: python, recursion, python-turtle

I am going through Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures using Python and am a bit confused on the recursion part. The code is as follows:

```
def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(75,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

I understand the idea of recursion I am just having trouble visualizing it in this specific problem. When this program executes and tree(75,t) is called it should run in the following steps:

1. branchLen > 5 therefore line 3 executes
2. t.forward(75)
3. t.right(20)
4. tree(75-15,t) this is where my confusion arises, does this then go back up and execute lines 2-3 over and over until branchLen < 5? So the steps would be
5. t.forward(60)
6. t.right(20)
7. tree(60-15,t)
8. t.forward(45) and so on until branchLen < 5 which would then execute line 6? Am I understanding this correctly or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well it doesn't "go back up" in terms of a GOTO command, but it creates another "instance" of this function running, with its own execution cursor, which indeed starts back at the top. The cursor of the parent function remains where the sub `tree()` was called, until it returns, then goes on executing from there. This happens everytime a recursive call is made - all those have their own execution cursor, of which only the most "inner" is currently going forward line by line, until a `return`, after which the parent cursor gets to move again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and for more knowledge of the technical terms which I do not possess yet:). I understand completely now

Comment: @Jeronimo sorry for another question but on the second recursive tree() call, as you stated it does start back at the top. Does this mean it also calls the first sub tree() recursively as it executes back down to itself? Sorry if that doesn't make sense. The multiple recursive calls is what confuses me haha

Comment: @Jeronimo ahh I do fully understand now haha, the nested recursion calls confused me but I was able to run it in debugger with breakpoints and see exactly what it does line by line. It's essentially creating another "instance" inside of an the "instance" (which are both in the parent instance) that was created in the very first sub tree() call